# Expected specifier qualifier list

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have two classes.One is view1 and other is view2.when i declare like this it is displaying error that "Expected Specifier qualifier list before view1".

code is :

```
@interface view1 : UIViewController 
{
 view2 *v2;
}
@interface view2 : UIViewController 
{
 view1 *v1;
}
```

Kindly help me thanks in advance.

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your code to make it more readable. Is that really the exact code you're trying to compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the @class directive to tell the compiler that the classes exist before you use them. If the two header files were to #include each other, then the compiler gets confused and you get an error like that.

view1.h:

```
@class view2;

@interface view1 : UIViewController
{
    view2 *v2;
}
```

view2.h

```
@class view1;

@interface view2 : UIViewController
{
    view1 *v1;
}
```

Then make sure that each of the .m files #import both header files.